# Set material color with unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am working on a game in UNITY. For this game so far I have 3 cubes that I wish to target. I have them set up in an array and when I hit tab the targets switch between them based on distance. This is all fine but I have run into a pickle and it is that I wish to have the cubes I target turn red for visual representation. I seen on Youtube that people used the following line of code :

```
selectedTarget.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
```

However this does not work for me. I then seen a comment saying :
The function to render was deprecated. Below should work...

```
selectedTarget.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
```

This code does not work for me either. I get no errors mind you, it runs fine but the cubes do not turn red. Has anyone any idea on whether or not I am doing this right? I will post the entire script below and the code I am on about is in selectedTarget(). Any help would be appreciated and thank you!

```
private void SelectTarget(){
    selectedTarget.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `SelectTarget` is being called? You could step through your code with a debugger, or add a simple [`Debug.Log`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) message that should show up in your console window.

Comment: Yeah I am when the games running I can see he active targets changing in the side window :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the very very very same problem. I had no errors. You need to be able to set the color property on the material, and only CERTAIN shaders have this color property. I had to use for example Self-Illuminated/Bumped instead of say Mobile/VertexLit. Then changing the color should be fine as you can see a Main Color property in the editor/inspector.

Also make sure your mesh has Materials. If you don't have Materials, even if it's blank or a placeholder else it won't work! I'd create a texture preferably white colored and small like 5x5. Then attach the texture to your cube. After you attach it you can color it!

I've done cool stuff in my game with Color.Lerp, it'll fade from one color to the next! This example below ping pongs from white to red when the player is hit by an enemy indicating damage!

```
transform.renderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(Color.white, Color.red, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 3 * speedLerp, 1.0));
```

Comment: I cant up vote your answer yet need more rep but yeah I'm glad I'm not the only one but I don't fully understand what you mean because I am new to UNITY sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Tile : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector2 gridPos = Vector2.zero;
    Renderer r;
    public Color colorStart = Color.red;
    public Color colorEnd = Color.green;
    public float duration = 1.0F;
    private float lerp;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        r = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        lerp = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, duration) / duration;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

    void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        r.material.color = Color.Lerp(colorStart, colorEnd, lerp);
        //r.material.color = Color.black;
        Debug.Log("X pos = "+ gridPos.x + "Y pos = "+ gridPos.y);
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        r.material.color = Color.Lerp(Color.white, Color.white,lerp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

set a bool type for color like

bool colorchange = false;

```
    public void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
    {


            Debug.Log ("collide");

            colorchange = true;

            if (colorchange) {
                    transform.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.red;
            }
    }
```

Comment: There's no need for a bool here, seen as though you change it to `true` as soon as you collide. The code could be narrowed down to `public void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)   {    transform.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.red;    }` It would still do the same thing.